# Upload image to server from imagepath stored in Sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

The app does the following initially

1. Get data from user including image and store in Sqlite database.
2. image path is stored in Sqlite db.

The aim of the app is to upload the data automatically and I am able to do that successfully using BroadcaseReciever for text using Volley but stuck as I don't know how the process to upload the image from Android.

1. I am able to retrieve the image path from the database but not sure what to do next.

I have done fair research but not getting solution when comes to upload image to server from imagepath stored in Sqlite.
Below is image path example stored in sqlite. ( I am a beginner in Android)

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1547728376728.jpg
```

Below code that I am working from.
PS : I believe the purpose of getimagepath method would be to 1. find the image 2. convert it into bytes 3. pass to Volley. I am stuck on 1. and the code might be wrong.

```
    package com.example.narendra.e5.activities.Connectivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.narendra.e5.activities.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.narendra.e5.activities.others.AppSingleton;
import com.example.narendra.e5.activities.others.MySingleton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class NetworkMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context context;
    public Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (checkNetworkConnection(context)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase database=db.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor=db.getdataIncoming(database);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){

                final String incoming=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOMINGTIME));
                Toast.makeText(context, incoming, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final String INVENID=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INVENIDAPP));
                final String imageurl=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SLIP_IMAGE));

                // get image path  from database and convert it into bitmap
                // Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageurl);
               // bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap();

                StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DatabaseHelper.SERVER_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                                    String getResponse=jsonObject.getString("response");
                                    if (getResponse.equals("OK")){
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Response ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        //db.deleteOfflineSaveOutgoingDetails(INVENID);




                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Response error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
                ){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("name",incoming);
                       // params.put("image",getimagepath(imageurl));
                        return params;
                    }
                }
                        ;
                MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);


            }
        }

    }
    public  boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }
    public  String getimagepath(Intent imageurl){
      // File imagepath=new File(String.valueOf(imageurl));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Uri imagePath = imageurl.getData();
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(imagePath));
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,60,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgByte=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT);






    }
}
```

Comment: search for any blog.

Comment: http://codesfor.in/how-to-upload-image-to-server-as-base64-encoded-string/

Comment: Hi @NoumanCh, The problem comes when it ask for Uri targetUri = data.getData(); and not sure how to transfer it via intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by correcting the method `public  String getimagepath(Intent imageurl)`
to this:

```
 public  String getimagepath(String imageurl){
  // File imagepath=new File(String.valueOf(imageurl));
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //Uri imagePath = imageurl.getData();
    if (imageurl !=null){
       // Uri imagePath = Uri.fromFile(new File(imageurl));


        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageurl);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,60,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgByte=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    else {

        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `POST` you can use `JsonObjectRequest` like this way. No need to override `getParams` method.

```
            HashMap<String,String> maps=new HashMap<>();

            maps.put("name",incoming);
            maps.put("image",getimagepath(imageurl));

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, YOUR_URL, new JSONObject(maps), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {



                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {



                }
            });
            jsonObjectRequest.setTag("TAG");
            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(2,0f));
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Hi Zaid, Thank you for your response but I belive my method "getimagepath" might be incorrect since I am passing intent(if I don't Uri imagePath = imageurl.getData(); doesn't work ) but I am saving the image as string final String imageurl=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SLIP_IMAGE));

Comment: You didn't mention this in question.

Comment: Hi  @Zaid, I am sorry for that but I was trying to add bits and pieces together from different sources. One video was showing the same but it was inside the activity and not from service class. I believe the purpose of getimagepath method would be to 1. find the image 2. convert it into bytes 3. pass to Volley.  I am stuck on 1.